# Tightly wrap gaps in background of multiple lines of text in TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I have written XML code to display a TextView with a green background:

[image]

However, I would like the space to the left and right of the text on the second line to be fully transparent without any green background -- generally wrapping closer to the text.

Here is an image depicting what part should be transparent on the left side (though I intend both sides to be transparent).

[image]

Now I am aware that I can accomplish this by using two TextViews placed above each other and splitting up the text in the Java code between the two views.  Since they would be separate then they would each wrap and therefore the text on the bottom view would get wrapped tightly, not being affected/expanded by the wrapping of the view on top.

However, ideally I would like to do this in the XML or with a more elegant solution.  Can this be done with XML or do I need to stick with my proposed solution of using multiple TextViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know Graphic Text Mixed before? This code will help you:

```
String str="this bit of text spans more than one line.Words words words";
    int bstart=0;
    int bend=str.length();

    SpannableStringBuilder style=new SpannableStringBuilder(str);
    style.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorGreenTra)),bstart,bend, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    TextView tvColor=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_color);
    tvColor.setText(style);
```

and in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_color"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="this bit of text spans more than one line.Words words words"
    />
```

The effect：
[image]

Comment: I think we can't set the background by system api in XML.If you just want  use XML to do this,maybe you have to draw a view which extends TextView.But  SpannableStringBuilder is very powerful.We always use it work on barrage.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.  Is it very difficult to add padding to this?

Comment: It is not difficult to add padding to TextView.

Comment: I mean with the spanned background.  Just adding padding in the xml or in java regularly doesn't affect the background with SpannableStringBuilder.